# Typescript compiler complaining about external d.ts files declared in a subdirectory

Tags: typescript, amd

I've gota standard web application directory structure with some folders under the `javascripts` directory. Directly under `javascripts` I have my entry point file, `main.ts`, and it looks like this:

```
import ext = require("./shared/extern");

var testval = "3"
export class main{
    print(additional:string){
        console.log(additional+ext.culture());
    }

}
```

Under a subdirectory of `javascripts`, called `shared`, I just have one file, `extern.d.ts`, and it looks like this:

```
declare module extern{
    function culture(): {
        name: string;
    }
}
```

I want this code to work because the resulting js works with my existing application. However, running

```
tsc --m amd main.ts
```

complains that `File './shared/extern.d.ts' is not an external module.` despite still generating the accurate files. I'd like to integrate these changes into my build system but it will fail due to these errors.
I've investigated using the reference path tags and

```
declare module "extern" { export = Assert; }
```

in the code but that generates js code that won't resolve in my project.

Anybody have any idea how to resolve these errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I was missing the `export = extern;` at the bottom of `extern.d.ts`. The extern files need to look like this:

```
declare module extern{
    function culture(): {
        name: string;
    }
}

export = extern;
```

Now it works.

Comment: That can be reduced to: `export declare function culture(): { name: string; };`

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
declare module "extern"{
    export function culture(): {
        name: string;
    }
}
```

And then load `extern` using either commonjs node_modules or AMD shim.

Comment: My only concern with this solution is that I may have a lot of these libraries that I we be writing d.ts files for. My knowledge of requirejs (amd) is still developing but the shim configuration seems to be designed to be used on legacy scripts. The extern script is defined as a proper amd module, just not written in typescript.

Comment: `I may have a lot of these libraries that I we be writing d.ts files for.` many of these should already have a `.d.ts` file written for you: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped And these are written using this pattern

Comment: Yes, I used those `.d.ts` files for my jquery, knockout references. I suppose I should have specified that extern is a module that I will eventually rewrite in typescript. From my perspective, it makes sense to keep `export = extern;` in the .d.ts until i replace the file with the proper .ts file. I suppose I could write a shim config to work, but my method seems more straight forward.